# DiffUtil not focusing on the current adapter position when switch between GRID and LINEAR

Tags: android

I'm using DiffUtil on RecyclerView, but there is a problem here. With SMALL_MODE, i currently see the 5th item in the adapter. When i switch to GRID_MODE, it restarts the position. I want it keeps the current position of the item i'm focusing (5th) not restart from the beginning position.  Please help me.

```
public void changeLayout(int viewMode){

    List<Item> oldList = adapter.getItems();
    List<Item> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++) {
        Item currentItem = oldList.get(i);

        if(viewMode == HeaderTitle.LARGE_MODE){
            if(currentItem instanceof NewsItem){
                NewsItem currentNewsItem = (NewsItem) currentItem;
                NewsItem newItem = new LargeNewsItem(currentNewsItem.getNews());
                newList.add(newItem);
            }else{
                newList.add(currentItem);
            }

            LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
        } 

        else if (viewMode == HeaderTitle.SMALL_MODE){
            if(currentItem instanceof NewsItem){
                if(count % 7 == 6){
                    NewsItem currentNewsItem = (NewsItem) currentItem;
                    NewsItem newItem = new TripleNewItem(currentNewsItem.getNews());
                    newList.add(newItem);
                }else{
                    NewsItem currentNewsItem = (NewsItem) currentItem;
                    NewsItem newItem = new SingleNewsItem(currentNewsItem.getNews());
                    newList.add(newItem);
                }
                count++;
            }else{
                newList.add(currentItem);
            }

            LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);

        } 

        else if (viewMode == HeaderTitle.GRID_MODE){
            if(currentItem instanceof NewsItem){
                NewsItem currentNewsItem = (NewsItem) currentItem;
                NewsItem newItem = new LargeNewsItem(currentNewsItem.getNews());
                newList.add(newItem);
            }else{
                newList.add(currentItem);
            }

            StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
    }

    //DiffUtil here
    adapter.updateData(newList);
}
```

**DiffUtil**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

....
   public void updateData(@NonNull List<Item> newsListItem) {
       final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
             new ItemUtilCallback(items, newsListItem), false);
       items = newsListItem;
       diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
   }
}
```